# Extract not sending WHERE conditions to SQL Server in DI Studio

Tags: sql-server, sas

I have a Job where I want to bring rows over from a SQL Server data source to a SAS data set.

In my Extract task, I have a condition applied as follows:

`datepart(LastUpdated) eq '14Nov2017'd;`

This connects to a SQL Server view which we'll call `vw.Sales`.

When I check what is running on the SQL instance, it looks like it is selecting the WHOLE of the view, which is 650+ million rows.  Obviously I don't want that all brought into work and then  filtered down.

Unless I am missing something and that what I can see as the running query is the subselect, can anyone identify how I can ensure my `WHERE` condition is passed through to SQL correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that SAS is indeed doing a 'SELECT *' on the table and processing your query on the SAS server rather than having your SQL server executing the query.

The reason is that SAS does not know how to translate your query to SQL server language likely because of the `datepart` function.

Your options are either to rewrite that query to something that SAS will be able to translate or to do your extract with explicit pass-through in a 'custom code' node.

As far as rewriting goes, you could maybe try something like:

```
where '14NOV2017:00:00:00'dt le lastupdated lt '15NOV2017:00:00:00'dt
```

Comment: Bingo-  I changed it to `LastUpdated ge '14Nov2017:00:00:00'dt` and it passed through correctly.  Thanks